group by pandas while retaining all rows and columns
enter image description here
My dataframe looks like above screenshot without the last column. Pasting print(df) below.
ID1 ID2 INTERNAL_ID DDD_OUTLET_ID   SRA_2   SRA_4   Prd_Name    Doses   Data_Available
3   3   C344205     93449151    93449151    ASN        PCV20    30     DDD Level
3   3   C375032     93449151    93449151    ASN        PCV20    30     DDD Level
3   3   C390019     93449151    93449151    ASN        PCV20    30     DDD Level
3   2   C10317637   94002154    94002154    ASN        PCV13    0      DDD Level
3   2   C10350055   94002154    94002154    ASN        PCV13    0      DDD Level
3   2   C10317637   94002154    94002154    ASN        PCV20    90     DDD Level
3   2   C10350055   94002154    94002154    ASN        PCV20    90     DDD Level
3       M990134     85027174    85027174    ASN        PCV13    0      DDD Level
3       M990134     85027174    85027174    ASN        PCV13    0      DDD Level
3       C1007843    85027174    85027174    ASN        PCV13    0      DDD Level
3       C1007843    85027174    85027174    ASN        PCV20    30     DDD Level

I want to perform group by on the above data in pandas based on Assoc ID, SRA_2 and Prd_Name, and get the count of each group in a new column 'Cnt' while retaining all the same rows and columns.
So i start with 11x18 shape dataframe and end up with 11x19 shape dataframe with the new count column from group by.
Is there any alternatives?
I am using transform but not getting the desired result.
df['Cnt'] = df.groupby(['Assoc_ID', 'SRA_2', 'Prd_Name'])['SRA_2'].transform('count')


Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your post so as to share all code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images. To share dataframes: copy-paste the output of print(df) or print(df.to_dict()). Also please replace tag [Python-3.x] with [Python].

Good, now [mre]: especially since your dataframe has too many columns to fit in your print window or you haven't set it up for full width usage, keep only the columns of interest for your question, namely: Assoc ID, SRA_2 and Prd_Name, plus one of your choice representing the payload of all other unused columns. You may find this advice summarized in [ask].

...and finally [code block] :)

Does this answer your question? Aggregation in Pandas

Use print(df.to_markdown()) and paste the result in your post. It works with stackoverflow format.

maybe create minimal working code with mininal data (directly in code) - so we could simply copy and run it. And you could also show expected result for these data. And put it all in question, not in comments. It will be more readable and more people may see it - so more people may help you.

Can you explain why transform('count') isn't getting what you desire?

Your code to group and count the data is correct, but I didn't find Assoc_ID column in the DataFrame, not in text, neither in the screenshot.
Try this code to test the idea of counting:
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'b': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    'c': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['count'] = df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['c'].transform('count')

print(df)

Maybe you are doing some changes on the dataframe before the counting, provide the full code to see if there are another problems.

In the screenshot, column Association_ID is same as Assoc_ID. In text not all columns are included.

Welcome to SO! Your suggestion replicates what OP claims to be doing already, just you do it in a reproducible way for us. The thing is, we are still waiting for @NoobMaster27 to clarify the actual problem: what is their expected output, what they think is wrong with their current output. Even what is their current output... The question is for now rather unclear.
